# Two observers within the same app interfering with each other

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two observers within my app, one that is ordered, one that isn't. The unordered observer seems to interfere with the ordered observer's results.

My database looks like this:

```
"events" : {
    "Oo75nbcDsUK7vPWGDbnL" : {
      "queue" : {
          "K7THdbKzd2aSfaD9a0xmsszkReq1" : {
            "queuePosition" : 1
          },
          "R5UwSxlH3vhH6SjTNMGfMoiaGae2" : {
            "queuePosition" : 2
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I have a class that handles the observer creation for the real-time database with the following static function:

```
static func listenToRtdbDocument<T: JSONDecodable>(_ refString: String, eventType: DataEventType = .value, orderedByChild: String? = nil, limit: Int? = nil, fromCollection collection: Firebase.RtdbCollections? = nil, completion: @escaping (_ decodedDoc: T?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) -> DatabaseHandle {
    var query: DatabaseQuery
    if let orderedByChild = orderedByChild {
        query = rtdb.child(refString).queryOrdered(byChild: orderedByChild)
    } else {
        query = rtdb.child(refString)
    }

    if let limit = limit {
        query.queryLimited(toFirst: UInt(limit))
    }

    return query.observe(eventType, with: { snapshot in
        guard var docData = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else {
            completion(nil, nil)
            return
        }
        docData["id"] = snapshot.key
        let decodedDoc = T(json: docData)
        completion(decodedDoc, nil)
    }) { error in
        completion(nil, error)
    }
}
```

This creates the observer and then returns a `DatabaseHandle` reference. I use this function in two different places in my app. The first is inside a collection view cell model. This calls the function like so:

```
queuerRefString = "events/Oo75nbcDsUK7vPWGDbnL/queue/R5UwSxlH3vhH6SjTNMGfMoiaGae2"

func listenToQueuer(updateHandler: @escaping (QueuerJSONModel?) -> ()) {
    guard queuerListener == nil,
        let refString = queuerRefString else { return }

    queuerListener = FirebaseClient.listenToRtdbDocument(refString) { (queuer: QueuerJSONModel?, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }
        updateHandler(queuer)
    }
}
```

The second is from a view controller model. This view controller gets presented over the collection view cell:

```
queueRefString = "events/Oo75nbcDsUK7vPWGDbnL/queue"


func listenToQueue() {
    guard queueChildAddedListener == nil
        let refString = queueRefString else { return }

    queueChildAddedListener = FirebaseClient.listenToRtdbDocument(refString, eventType: .childAdded, orderedByChild: "queuePosition", limit: 25) { [weak self] (queuer: QueuerJSONModel?, error) in
        guard let strongSelf = self,
            let queuer = queuer,
            error == nil else {
                print("an error occurred")
            return
        }
        strongSelf.queuers?.append(queuer)
    }
}
```

For the ordered array observer, this always returns the current user first, and then the rest of the ordered queue. E.g. If the current user is at position 5, the `queuers` array will look like this:

```
5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

How can I stop them from interfering with each other??

**UPDATE**

How to reproduce:

Put this code in one view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
let test1 = Database.database().reference()
        .child("events/Oo75nbcDsUK7vPWGDbnL/queue/R5UwSxlH3vhH6SjTNMGfMoiaGae2")
        .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            guard var docData = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else {
                return
            }
            docData["id"] = snapshot.key
            let queuer = QueuerJSONModel(json: docData)!
            print("ok we got", queuer.queuePosition) // Prints out 2
        })
```

Then put this code in another view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
let test2 = Database.database().reference()
        .child("events/Oo75nbcDsUK7vPWGDbnL/queue")
        .queryOrdered(byChild: "queuePosition")
        .queryLimited(toFirst: 25)
        .observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            guard var docData = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else {
                return
            }
            docData["id"] = snapshot.key
            let queuer = QueuerJSONModel(json: docData)!
            print("ok we got", queuer.queuePosition) // Prints out 2, then 1
        })
```

First view the view controller that has `test1` in, then view the one with `test2` in. I use a tab bar controller to switch between the two.

Oddly, if these two pieces of code are put within the same `viewDidLoad` method of a view controller, then the ordered listener works as expected.

Comment: Observers don't interfere with each other.  Each one operates fully independently of each other.

Comment: @DougStevenson That's what I hoped but when I comment out the second observer that I've stated in my code, the first one returns objects in the correct order. Btw these are used in different parts of my app, so don't write to the same array or anything.

Comment: What code is determining the output that you show?  Are you printing the contents of `myArray` or something?  Please edit the question to show all the code involved.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi, have updated my question with more code.

Comment: It's hard to see what all you're doing here (I think there is still code missing).  But is it possible that that the two queries are running simultaneously, but both updating some shared data structure in a non-deterministic way?

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't think so... For example if I put a print statement in the `queueChildAddedListener` to print out the `queuePosition` of each item returned, the current user's `queuePosition` will be returned first from the listener. That's coming directly from the firebase observer completion block. Which is why I think they are interfering somehow.

Comment: I think you're going to have to strip out all the extra code here and just show the minimal observers that illustrate the problem, that anyone can easily reproduce.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added an update to my question with steps on how to reproduce. I still can't figure this one out :/

Comment: @Tometoyou , could be your fundamental misunderstanding is how "ordering" works in results from FB ?

Comment: @Fattie Please explain what my fundamental misunderstanding is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Firebase support's response to my question:

> Apparently, this is an intended behavior. The idea of childAdded is, here is what you have retrieved so far, and what hasn't been added yet. So the childAdded gives R5UwSxlH3vhH6SjTNMGfMoiaGae2 as your preloaded data, and comes back with K7THdbKzd2aSfaD9a0xmsszkReq1 as your new data.

This way, even if you have requested it to be ordered, it won't necessarily come back ordered, if you have preloaded data on your device.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're observing is because of to the way 'value' events are different from 'childAdded' events.

In your first observer (using `.value`), you're simply requesting all the data from `events/Oo75nbcDsUK7vPWGDbnL/queue/R5UwSxlH3vhH6SjTNMGfMoiaGae2` in a single snapshot.  If any data under the location changes while that observer is still added, your observer will get invoked again with a snapshot of everything at that location.

In your second observer (using `.childAdded`), you're requesting that your observer be called once for each child at `events/Oo75nbcDsUK7vPWGDbnL/queue`.  If you have two children there, your observer will be called once for each child.  As new children are added at that location, your observer will get called again, once for each new one.

The observers are not interfering with each other.  They're just doing different things.

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't explain why the `.childAdded` observer isn't called in the order I have specified? I do want to use `.value` for `events/Oo75nbcDsUK7vPWGDbnL/queue/R5UwSxlH3vhH6SjTNMGfMoiaGae2` and I do want to use `.childAdded` for `events/Oo75nbcDsUK7vPWGDbnL/queue`, for the reasons you have specified, as also stated in the documentation. Have you tried reproducing my problem?

Comment: My temporary solution is to remove the `.value` observer when I want to observe `.childAdded`, and then it produces my desired results. This definitely feels like a hack though.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong by accessing shared data between the two.  They simply do not interfere with each other.  If they did, there would be a lot of buggy apps out there.  In practice, apps app dozens or more simultaneous listeners that each function as expected.

Comment: I definitely am not. I have created a new project and managed to reproduce my problem exactly how I described. Is there anywhere I can send this so you guys can take a look at it? You will have to create your own db to mimic mine with your own login details though.